Type errors in mocking AWS SDK functions in TypeScript using Jest
I am trying to mock the deleteObject and upload AWS SDK functions being used in my backend routes:
    const params: AWS.S3.DeleteObjectRequest = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: fileName,
    };

    // Delete the object from the bucket
    await s3.deleteObject(params).promise();

const params: AWS.S3.PutObjectRequest = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: filename,
      Body: file.data,
    };

    // Upload file to S3
    const data = await s3.upload(params).promise();

Currently I have tried mocking them like this in my Jest files:
// ...

jest.mock("aws-sdk");

// ...

const s3 = new AWS.S3() as jest.Mocked<S3>;
s3.upload.mockResolvedValue({});

But get an error:
'Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

I have also tried:
// ...

// Mock the S3 class and its upload method
const mockUpload = jest.fn();
jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  return {
    S3: jest.fn(() => ({
      upload: mockUpload,
    })),
  };
});

// ...

 mockUpload.mockReturnValue({
      promise: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
        Location: "https://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.jpg",
      }),
    });

But this gives a similar error:
Argument of type '{ Location: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

I have tried something similar with the getSignedUrl function and that works alright with no type errors:
const signedUrl = "https://signed-url.com/somefile.txt";
// Mock the signed URL generation
    jest
      .spyOn(AWS.S3.prototype, "getSignedUrlPromise")
      .mockResolvedValue(signedUrl);


upload doesn't return a promise, so why mockResolvedValue? First rule of test doubles: they must match the interface of the thing they're standing in for.

Did you find the fix?
